# How to make sure a particular dependency is only loaded/activated for certain profiles?

Tags: maven, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gcp

The plan is to have a `prod` profile for the production environment which runs in tandem with a Cloud SQL Postgres-instance.

For this I require the `spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql` dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

The problem: Whatever I try, this dependency seems to get injected to the Spring Boot auto-config chain somehow.

If I run the server locally I'd get

```
Error creating bean with name 'com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.firestore.GcpFirestoreAutoConfiguration': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: 
No qualifying bean of type 'com.google.cloud.spring.core.GcpProjectIdProvider' available:
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

If thought I could fix this by chosing a different `<scope>` for he dependency, but nothing I tried works - except `<scope>test</scope>`.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

However, this is of course not what I want either.

All I want to do is declare `spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql` and *not* influence the application in any way except certain profiles, like `prod`, are activated.

I've tried the following:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gcp:
      core:
        enabled: false
      sql:
        enabled: false
```

But I'd still get the same exception.

Is there a way do configure this the way I want to except for removing the dependency from the root?